# How to simplify a midi file similar to the same limitations of a player piano

Tags: piano, composition, sheet-music, software, midi

Please bear with me because I'm very new with working with music. I've been searching for a really long time and reading the manuals of various software I've download and have not been able to figure this out.

What I'm trying to accomplish exactly is:

1. To simplify a midi file. By that I mean making the velocity/volume the same and the pitch bending removed and a way to modify the tempo.
2. All the different tracks and channels merged into one track and channel. I'm using midi editor http://midieditor.sourceforge.net/ however, if another program can accomplish this better I'd rather use that. The output has to be midi.

The end result would be a midi file with one track that if played with a piano soundfont would mimic the results of a piano roll on a real simple foot powered player piano.
[image]
This is my first question here on music so sorry in advance if I'm using the wrong terminology I'm open to suggestions on how to improve my question. I will respond to any comments quickly and edit my question as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I once wrote a program in C++ which parses, manipulates and writes Midi-files. It was one of my first programs I wrote, thus the code is probably not the best - but as far as I remember, it worked quite well.

If you have programming skills, I could send you the source-code. The things you mention above, should be implemented quite easily, if I remember my code correctly.

Comment: I'm still really new to the world of programming so I'm not sure, but I'd appreciate that. What language is it in?

Comment: It is written in C++. I used MSVC as development environment.

Comment: I'd like that please, if you're willing to share. My friend knows C++ he might be willing to help me out. It's not the actually solution I'm looking for because I'm really looking for GUI. Anyway I give you +1

Comment: Please send me an email: tommsch@gmx.at